# how to specify native library path in JRuby?

Tags: java, linux, jruby, java.library.path

I am trying to initialize JUnixSocket in JRuby but it is failing as it is unable to locate the native library. I am getting error :

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load junixsocket library, tried [/opt/newsclub/lib-native/libjunixsocket-linux-1.7-amd64.so, /opt/newsclub/lib-native/libjunixsocket-linux-1.5-amd64.so, lib:junixsocket-linux-1.7-amd64, lib:junixsocket-linux-1.5-amd64]; please define system property org.newsclub.net.unix.library.path

Command which I am trying to execute:

```
irb(main):015:0> java_import 'org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocket'
irb(main):016:0> AFUNIXSocket.newInstance()
```

I have the following libraries in folder lib:
libjunixsocket-linux-1.5-amd64.so  libjunixsocket-linux-1.5-i386.so.

Is it possible to specify path of library in irb so that it can get the library? Any approach which can solve above problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify -J-Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your jvm server configuration file.
Here $LD_LIBRARY_PATH should contain paths to your native libraries.